# DateTime ISO 8601 without timezone component

Tags: datetime, localization, iso8601

I've been doing work with parsing datetime strings for our international application.  I'm running into an interpretation issue that I can't seem to find a definitive answer.  **Should an ISO 8601 datetime string without a timezone component be treated as local time?**

Per [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) (which I don't want to base my business decisions off of):

> If no UTC relation information is given with a time representation,
>   the time is assumed to be in local time.

However, I can't find supporting documentation via ISO or any other generally acceptable source of truth.  Everything that I've found talks about how to handle offsets for local time (e.g. +/- 0500, etc). Assuming local time in these cases would help me substantially as my users can submit the same date for all regions without needed to calculate the specific offset for each region.

For example:

```
2012-01-01T00:00:00 # Convert to local
2012-01-01T00:00:00Z # Zulu/UTC...don't convert
```

Is there an established interpretation for timezone-less ISO 8601 strings?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Section 4.2.2 of ISO 8601 gives examples with no TZ designator saying they are local times. 4.2.4 says UTC times use the 'Z' designator. Of course it always raises the question "local time where?"...

> The zone designator is empty if use is made of local time in accordance with 4.2.2.2 through 4.2.2.4, it is the UTC designator [Z] if use is made of UTC of day in accordance with 4.2.4 and it is the difference-component if use is made of local time and the difference from UTC in accordance with 4.2.5.2.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I was looking for. It's kind of lame that the ISO documentation isn't "publicly" available for free, which is why I missed it the first time.  God bless people who upload it anyway :)

There is an inherent attribute in the user input that specifies region, so the "where" aspect is already taken care of.

Answer (score -1):

Without the timezone designator, the datetime string will be interpreted as local time -- but as local time to the SERVER.

If your users are in different timezones, the dates they submit without TZ information will be interpreted incorrectly with your local TZ offset.

Comment: Who says it has to be interpreted as the local time of the server, and not some other appropriate place?

Comment: Let me be more precise: it will be interpreted as local time of the environment where you're running the code. If the code is running on the backend, the dates will be interpreted with the TZ offset local to the server. If the server is in a different timezone than the client, you will be confused.

Comment: I would still say this is application-specific. Local time is local time, it does not have a time zone unless and until one is added.

Comment: But yes, if you start doing operations on a local date, many libraries will interpret a local date/time as if it was in the local computer's timezone by convention I suppose!